# python gi.repository.gtk menu separators are missing

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3, pygobject

I want to show simple popup menu with right click, menu works right but menu separators are missing, I searched similar examples but they all using pygtk but I'm using gi.repository I don't know is my code wrong or this problem is all about libraries.

my code is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Win(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Win, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400,280)
        self.button = Gtk.Button()
        self.add(self.button)
        self.button.connect("button-press-event", self.button_press)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()

    def button_press(self,widget,event):
        if event.button == 3:
            self.menu = Gtk.Menu()
            self.menu_copy = Gtk.MenuItem("Copy")
            self.menu_paste = Gtk.MenuItem("Paste")
            self.menu_select_all = Gtk.MenuItem("Select All")
            self.menu.append(self.menu_copy)
            self.menu.append(self.menu_paste)
            # separator 1
            self.menu.append(Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem())
            # separator 2
            self.menu.append(Gtk.MenuItem())

            self.menu.append(self.menu_select_all)

            self.menu.show_all()
            self.menu.popup(None, None, None, None, event.button, event.get_time())
            pass
def main():
    app = Win()
    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
```

and here is the screenshot of my menu [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywkST.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of pygobject do you have? I submitted a patch for that back in June and it was fixed in 3.3.4: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=670575

If the separator works properly when you use `Gtk.SeparatorMenuItem.new()` instead of the constructor than you know it's the aforementioned bug.

Comment: this is the explanation what i'm looking for, i aplied the patch and problem gone, thanks a lot.